# How to know when an activity finishes a layout pass?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a background thread that updates the UI of my activity, after the `onCreate()`. It can be adding layouts, or changing the size of others.

I simply want to detect when the layout pass is finished in my activity, to be able to manually update the positions of others views that directly depend on the layouts that were just adde or modified.

For now, I just use a `Handler` with a `postDelayed runnable` that does the job, after a small delay, around 50-100 ms after the modifs that triggers the `requestLayout()`.

It works, but we can obviously see the delay. I would like to do the job as soon as possible. In a view code it's simple to detect the measurement pass, but I don't find how to solve this directly in the  activity.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

A GlobalLayoutListener will fire an event on completion of a layout. Would that suit your needs?

```
View myView=findViewById(R.id.myView);
  myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                //At this point the layout is complete and the 
                //dimensions of myView and any child views are known.
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just ran a test and it appears `onGlobalLayout` is called at least 3 times on initial layout.

Answer (score 2):

in addition to Phillip Fitzsimmons accepted answer, which is correct, I would also note that if someone needs to know the size in the view itself, the method:

```
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
  super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
  // your code here
}
```

can be overridden and it will be called after the layout pass.

Comment: Although this is correct, I want to add that this can be called twice or even more often in some layouts, where the measurement process will be called recursivly (weights etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`

per the docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener

> At this point, all views in the tree have been measured and given a frame.

Only if a view in your tree requests another layout pass, will any layout bounds change. You could also use similar technique using the `ViewTreeObserver.OnDrawListener` to get the callback even later

```
myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            // view is measured and laid out
        });
```