# Dynamic change text size for maintain 1 line?

Tags: java, android, fonts, size, dynamically-generated

I'm 17 and I'm italian. This is my first app.

I've foolishly thought this code for maintain 1 line on my switch independently from the screen:

```
Inside at OnCreate()
   
while(SWITCH.getLineCount()>1)
                SWITCH.setTextSize(SWITCH.getTextSize()-1);
```

obviously does not work..
why?

I've read a lot of ask but I have not yet figured out how to set the font size dynamically based on the size of the screen.

**Thank you very much.**

EDIT: for distraction I had written

*(SWITCH.getLineCount()-1)*

instead of

*(SWITCH.getTextSize()-1)*,

but still does not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the size of the font of a JLabel to take the maximum size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715118/how-to-change-the-size-of-the-font-of-a-jlabel-to-take-the-maximum-size)

Comment: You sure you want `getLineCount()` in `setTextSize()`? Wouldn't it be `getTextSize()`?

Comment: @mikeM. I've used getTextSize() to get the size and reduce it by one for loop. Do you understand me?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but your logic is flawed. You want to decrement the size until the text fits on one line. `getLineCount()` does not return the text size, so subtracting 1 from that and setting it as the new size makes no sense. The line in the loop should be `SWITCH.setTextSize(SWITCH.getTextSize()-1);`

Comment: @mikeM. absolutely right! I'm a wimp and I was convinced that he had written getTextSize() , thanks boy. I'll try..

Comment: I should mention, though, that I'm not sure this way will work. You might give cyanide's answer a shot, too.

Comment: @MikeM. SWITCH.setTextSize(SWITCH.getTextSize()-1) not work.. I want try the cyanide's code but i don't understand some things.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **your TextView has android:maxWidth value**.

The following function:

- Gets Maximum width
- Uses Paint.measureWidth to check the actual width
- If the actual width is more than maximum, the font size is reduced proportionally.
- The loop continues until the width becomes less than maximum.
- For safety reason I introduced *iterCount* to ensure than the loop will eventually end.

I didn't test the code, but the idea should be clear:

```
private void adjustTextSize(TextView tv,  final String text) {
    float maxWidth = tv.getMaxWidth() * 0.9f;

    Paint p = tv.getPaint();
    float fontSize = p.getTextSize();
    float txtWidth;

    int iterCount = 10;

    while (--iterCount >= 0 &&  (txtWidth = p.measureText(text)) > maxWidth)  
        p.setTextSize(fontSize *= (maxWidth / txtWidth));

}
```

Comment: Correct, I have fixed that. Silly me!

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand how the text can get over the max width.. does not it impossible?

Comment: I've try the code and the font resize . But i don't understand how much i must set the MaxWidth..

Comment: You can omit maxWidth and use layout_width="match_parent". The trouble is that in this case you don't know the size untill layout is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit maxWidth and use layout_width="match_parent". The trouble is that in this case you don't know the size until layout is complete. See [How to know when an activity finishes a layout pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418868/how-to-know-when-an-activity-finishes-a-layout-pass) about notification when layout is complete.

From onGlobalLayout() you can use  tv.getWidth()

```
 final TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myView);

 tv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
       new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                float maxWidth = tv.getWidth() * 0.9f;

                String text = getResources().getString(R.string.myTextId); 
                float fontSize = tv.getTextSize();
                float txtWidth;

                int iterCount = 10;

                 while (--iterCount >= 0 &&  (txtWidth = tv.getPaint().measureText(text)) > maxWidth)  
                     tv.setTextSize(fontSize *= (maxWidth / txtWidth));

                 tv.setText(text);
             }
         });
```

I slightly changed the code to assign textSize to the TextView, rather than to the underlying Paint. It's more correct this way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this library [here](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) later, it does what you want to do

Just add the compile to your gradle and replace the `<TextView` in xml with `<me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView`, done, the magic is done, rs