# Calculate the empty area of a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, dimensions

I want to construct a generic function which receives a LinearLayout (or another view) and calculate the empty space left in it, so i know how many space i've to fit something into it

The main purpose of it is to set ads, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/profilePhotoRadius"
 />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/smallMargin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/smallMargin"
 />
<!-- bunch of other stuff here -->
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

then after in my code

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 this.adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        if (this.adView != null) {


            int width =   this.adView.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = this.adView.getHeight();
}
```

but running this code `width` and `height` are always zero... i tried to use `getWidth()` and result is always zero

how can i get the real value?

Comment: At onCreate while inflation is not finished all sizes are 0, they only have values after onLayout/onMeasure, check if the viewtreeobserver solution works for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418868/how-to-know-when-an-activity-finishes-a-layout-pass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OnCreate()` you are are just inflating the layout. The UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet.You are calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` too early.
You can try this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 this.adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
 this.adView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                touchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else {
                touchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

             float Width = this.adView.getWidth();
             float Height =this.adView.getHeight();
            ...
        }
    });
```

Comment: weird questions.... is there any way to do that without the `adview` in the xml? if i put all my stuff inside linear layout is there a way to get just the space left?

Answer (score 0):

Try it in  `onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)` method. 
From the documentation:

> This is the best indicator of whether this activity is visible to the
>   user