# I have a problem involving Handle.postDelay function in Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Basically i have a TextView which needs to move from right side to the other (I am testing something for a different project).Instead, everything is still. Nothing is executed.

Another thing to point out: If I remove the if statement, which is necessary in my case, everything works just fine. I thought the condition is false, so I put an else statement. Same thing happened - nothing. I tested whether or not the condition is false - it was true. So the code inside the if statement should've been executed.

Everything seems logical to me, but I could be wrong. Could you help me? What could I change? Do you have a different approach to my problem? Thanks!

P.S: The problem is not animating the TextView. The problem is the time delay.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.nicksoft.test;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int ind = -1;
    private Handler h = new Handler();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        r.run();
    }
    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(findViewById(R.id.textView).getX()>0) {
                findViewById(R.id.textView).setTranslationX(ind);
                ind--;
                h.postDelayed(r,5);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: As you can see in the XML file, i have a TextView on the right side which needs to every 5ms move 1px to the left until it reaches the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing works because `getX` returns 0. Inside `onCreate` stage `View` doesn't have real coordinates because layout haven't been built yet and `getX` returns default 0 and `postDelayed` isn't called. You call `r.run();` too early.

[You should wait until layout stage is finished.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8418868/how-to-know-when-an-activity-finishes-a-layout-pass) All views will get their coordinates. Then `getX` will return you something meaningful and your code will work.

If you don't 100% required to use such custom approach for "animation" use default platform ways e.g. `PropertyAnimator`

Answer (score 0):

Another way could could make doing simple animations cleaner is using the animate builder on the view itself. You may need to fetch the screen width as I have done if you wish to move across the whole screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nick);
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        findViewById(R.id.textView).animate().translationXBy(displayMetrics.widthPixels * -1).setDuration(displayMetrics.widthPixels * 5).setStartDelay(5L);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, for some reason nothing is happening. Maybe there is an error in your answer? Perhaps I haven't used it correctly. Could you check again, please? Thank you for helping!

Comment: What should your answer do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with the daimajia AndroidViewAnimations library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations ... you could simply slice it to the left, and then make it invisible...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

yourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
YoYo.with(Techniques.SlideOutLeft).duration(2500).playOn(yourTextView); //take 2500ms to slide
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            yourTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    },2500);}
```